# Просмотр видео с ограниченным доступом с youtube

Tags: asp.net, безопасность, youtube, youtube-api

Подскажите, кто знает. Заказчик хранит на youtube ряд видео с ограниченным доступом (т.е. просматривать видео можно только под его учеткой). Он хочет чтобы ASP.NET-приложение подключалось под этой учеткой к youtube и проигрывало пользователям видео.

Подключение к youtube через его API в приложении ASP.NET я реализовала, ID всех необходимых видео я забираю. Но при просмотре видео, сейчас нужно либо на соседней вкладке войти в учетку заказчика, либо будет выдано сообщение, что видео невозможно просмотреть, т.к. к нему ограничен доступ. Заказика это не устраивает из соображений безопасности (он не хочет давать кому-либо из пользователей данные своей учетки и не хочет, чтобы кто-либо из пользователей смог скопировать (украсть) у него эти видео). В связи с этим 2 вопроса:

1) Как сделать так, чтобы сразу пользователь видел видео, и ему не нужно было в браузере авторизовываться через учетку заказчика?

2) Возможно ли в странице просмотра, которую генерирует ASP.NET MVC приложение скрывать ссылку на видео из youtube (возможно есть вариант получения временных ссылок на видео из youtube, которые доступны только в течении некоторого времени)

Comment: *не хочет, чтобы кто-либо из пользователей смог скопировать (украсть) у него это видео* - пусть забудет об этом, если я могу посмотреть видео, значит я (и любой школьник) могу легко его скопировать, точка.

Comment: О вариантах savefrom.net и т.п. я ему объясняла, но, увы, я так понимаю, что ему негде хранить эти файлы на сервере, потому хочет хоть какую-то безопасность (хотя бы мнимую) и не раздавать всем данные своей учетки.